# VSIX plugin that builds a release, is it possible?

Tags: c#, vsix

so I have been working on a [VSIX plugin for visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFJx1.png) that makes an release build.
The current plugin consists of a command box that gives a messages, the message is either yes or no deppending on the existence of a certain file.
but that doesnt have a lot to do with what I want.

I have done research and I am unable to find any documentation or other people who tried this.
My colleague pointed me to a SolutionBuild Interface but that doesnt seem to have helped me at all. It does have some functionality that I would like (the Deploy method for instance) but just doesnt seem to be working properly.

in short. i want my little command plugin to be able to build a release build (of a project that is curently open like a simple windows form) to a defined loacation.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.4.4

Comment: This is a built in capability within VS, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2019, not sure why you would need to reinvent that wheel ;). I think your colleague’s on the right track! It may also behoove you to include the VS version.

Comment: You want your plugin or custom command button to release build of another (vsix) project? Instead of using in-built "Release" option?

Comment: the plugin should make a release build of an open project, the open project does not have to be a VSIX. it could be WinForm

Answer (score 0):

The procedure given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2019) may help you to **Release/Debug** to a defined location.

Comment: yes and no. i know i can change the directory it puts the files in. but i need code that makes certain build. then i need to put that build in a certain location.